# BigQuery CLI: Can i list all jobtypes of load to a specific dataset?

Tags: google-bigquery, command-line-interface

Using bq ls, how can I search for jobtype of load, where the data was loaded to a specific dataset, e.g. something like

`bq ls -j -all -jobtype="load" myproject:mydataset`

I can't quite get the syntax right, any ideas?

Best wishes

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can suggest.

You can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA for the details of [load jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs#example_2_load_job_history). In WHERE clause you can mention the job_type and dataset_id.

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql '
SELECT job_id, job_type, start_time,end_time,state, destination_table.dataset_id, destination_table.table_id
FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
WHERE job_type="LOAD" AND destination_table.dataset_id="mydataset"
'
```

There are more columns available in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA which provide more detials. Refer this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs#schema).

Answer (score 0):

There is a `filter` option that is unfortunately restricted to filtering labels only.

What about the following command with `grep`?

```
bq ls -j -a | grep load
```